# JavaScript Chrome printing multiple screens

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, printing-web-page

problem in Chrome printing multiple screens

the code below is designed to load records from a list of students and print the resulting screen for each student.

this works fine in browsers other than Chrome

Chrome does not display each students record result and thus prints multiple copies of just one student.

When the script finishes the last student record in the list is displayed so we know that the form request is being made successfully. It appears Chrome is not waiting for the form request to load or that it doesn't update the screen before getting to the print command.

```
function printAll() {
    var stdsObj = document.getElementById('stds');
    for ( var i = 0; i < stdsObj.options.length; i++ )  {
        showRec(i)
        printIframe("main")
    } 
}

function showRec(selRec) {
    var recID = '';
    var recName = '';
    var recNum = '';
    var stdsObj = document.getElementById('stds');
    recID = stdsObj.options[selRec].value;
    recName = stdsObj.options[selRec].text;
    recNum = selRec +1;  
    document.getElementById('recID').value = recID;
    document.getElementById('recName').value = recName;
    document.getElementById('recNum').value = recNum;
    document.getElementById('noCacheRec').value = Math.random();
    document.recList.submit()
}

function printIframe(id) {
    var iframe = document.frames ? document.frames[id] : document.getElementById(id);
    var ifWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe;
    ifWin.focus();
    ifWin.printMe();
    return false;
}
```

The form recList loads data into iframe "main"

```
<form id="recList" name="recList" action="ru_cse_view.pl" target="main">
```

printMe is a function in the iframe "main" that prints the iframe

```
function printMe() {
  window.print()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `recList.submit()` is doing? I'm also not aware of a `printMe()` function on an iFrame.

Comment: Sorry recList.submit() sends a form that loads into the iFrame "main".  printMe is a function in the iFrame "main" that does window.print()